# How to dectect silence in AVAudioRecorder?

Tags: iphone, audio-recording, avaudiorecorder

I use AVAudioRecorder for voice recording. Currently I use `averagePowerForChannel` and `peakPowerForChannel` to show a dynamic meter.

How can I detect silence (no body speaks for 1 second) and so I can stop the recording?

Comment: How to filter the initial silence duration while recording audio using AVAudiorecorder. Kindly let me know if there is any possibilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you are already showing a meter then surely you already have the answer?

You could simply sum the last n readings where n is the number of readings you take per second and then if the value is less than some threshold you set, you can declare it silence.

Comment: Since there will be different background noise in different environment, I am looking for a relative threshold rather than the hardcode the value at my working table ;-) Any idea?

Comment: All you need then is an adaptive threshold - you can get that by averaging the LOWEST power values determined over the most recent x seconds.